# QObject::connect fails at runtime, while linking thread's finished-signal to mapper's delateLater-slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot, qsignalmapper

i'm using C++ and Qt4.5.2 (requirement of the target system) in my project.
There is a need of a worker thread supplied with additional arguments/parameter, so i did the following (in short with deleted error handling/output):

```
bool _bRetVal = false;
COpgThread* _pParseThread = new COpgThread(); // COpgThread is subclassed from QThread to access the protected msleep-function
COpgWorker* _pParseWorker = new COpgWorker(); // COpgWorker is subclassed from QObject to provide: slots (process) and signals (finished, progress, error) for a COpgThread-instance
QSignalMapper* _pParseMapper = new QSignalMapper();
COpgParam _pParseParam = new COpgParam(m_sParseFile, m_sRegExpFile); // COpgParam is subclassed from QObject to handle user data for mapping

_pParseWorker->moveToThread(_pParseThread);
//#1 hookup error-signal from worker to errorParsing-function in this object
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseWorker, SIGNAL(error(int const)), this, SLOT(errorParsing(int const)));

//#2..3 hookup thread's started-signal to process-slot in the worker (via signal mapper for parameters/arguments)
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseThread, SIGNAL(started()), _pParseMapper, SLOT(map()));
_pParseMapper->setMapping(_pParseThread, _pParseParam);
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject*)), _pParseWorker, SLOT(process(QObject*)));

//#4 hookup progress-signal from worker to progessParsing-function in this object    
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseWorker, SIGNAL(progress(int const)), this, SLOT(progressParsing(int const)));

//#5 hookup finished-signal from worker to completedParsing-function in this object
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseWorker, SIGNAL(finished(int const)), this, SLOT(completedParsing(int const)));

//#6 when worker emits finished-signal, signal thread to quit (shutdown)
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseWorker, SIGNAL(finished(int const)), _pParseThread, SLOT(quit()));
//#7 when worker emits finished-signal, mark worker to be deleted
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseWorker, SIGNAL(finished(int const)), _pParseWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
//++++ this connect fails at runtime ++++
    //#8 when thread emits finished-signal, mark mapper to be deleted
    _bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseThread, SIGNAL(finished(int const)), _pParseMapper, SLOT(deleteLater()));
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//#9 when thread emits finished-signal, mark thread to be deleted
_bRetVal = QObject::connect(_pParseThread, SIGNAL(finished(int const)), _pParseThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
_pParseThread->start();
```

The whole code compiles without any errors, but the 8th connect fails at runtime. I thought, that when i create an instance of QSignalMapper ... it has to bee deleted sometime or other. Maybe it's wasted code. I'm not that familiar with Qt.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the 8th connect fails at runtime.

An error message is printed to stdout - what does it print?

btw: The QProcess::finished() signal is SIGNAL(finished(int)) - this might be your problem.

Comment: My project not a console application, so stdout is not visible by default. Is there an GetLastError-equivalent or do i have to read/redirect stdout manually? Is QProcess::finished() inherited by QThread::finished()? I will try to remove the const statemant in SIGNAL(finished(int)).

Comment: Thanks for pushing me to the right direction. Changing "connect(_pParseThread, SIGNAL(finished(int const))..." to connect(_pParseThread, SIGNAL(finished())..." solves this issue. The Copy&Paste-daemon got me ;-) because the QThread's-signal is "void finished()" (without arguments/parameters).

Comment: You can either set it as console application in your pro file:

CONFIG += console

Or add a Qt message handler: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

Comment: At the end, my project result in a library, which will be integrated into an existing Qt-GUI-application like a plugin. So i'm very restricted according project settings. Qt message handler is also not suitable for my project (Your link says: This function was introduced in Qt 5.0.). Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: There is a similar function available in Qt4: [qInstallMsgHandler](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler).
And the console application - you can use it at least for debug purposes - or do you program your library without a test executable?

Comment: Thanks. Your link is close to my target version, but i found the handler ([qInstallMsgHandler](https://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler)) in Qt4.5 as well. I will investigate that. I test my library in the targeted Qt-GUI-app (which is not from us). The vendor of that app, sells/provides a kind of a toolkit/framework with examples, documentation and project templates to develop/integrate such a plugin/library. So everybody can add own functionality/screens to the standard app. That's why i'm restricted in use of the right Qt version (has to match the app's Qt version).